# Django How to user FormSet with ListView

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm trying to use modelformset_factory with ListView to Update multiple rows in the model.

It works fine just subclassing the FormView, but I would like to pagenate it.

Comment: Look at [django's docs about Paginating a ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/pagination/#paginating-a-listview).

Comment: You can use Multiple Inheritance.